# What is the difference between {$Internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory} and ${Internal.Entry.Current.Directory}?

Tags: pentaho, relative-path, pentaho-spoon, pdi

In order to use as a relative path name in a transformation, which one to use?

```
${Internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory}
```

or

```
${Internal.Entry.Current.Directory}
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-15691):

> *`$Internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory` is deprecated since 6.0. Correct behavior would be to replace the same folder by `$Internal.Entry.Current.Directory`*

So use:

```
${Internal.Entry.Current.Directory}
```

if using PDI version with greater or equal to 6.0, and:

```
${Internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory}
```

if not.

Comment: Adding to that: the new variable replaces 4 variables, which each returned the folder of the current job/ transformation in a filesystem/repository. The new variable works in all 4 cases, the old ones need different variables in each one.